# Installing TBATS using Conda forge

Tags: python, forecasting, arima, moving-average

I am trying to use Python to do some forecasting on 1 year wind speed, one of the method is fbprophet. After sometime browsing I found out that I need to istall it with Conda Forge.

I am completely new in this, but it seems by changing channel I need to instal some packages(panda, numpy) again using Conda forge.

One of the missing pakcage is tbats, unfortunately I could not find a way to install it with COnda-forge, only the usual `pip install tbats`

Is there a way I could use both tbats and fbprophet at python together?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use both packages, conda environment can install packages using either `conda install` or `pip install`. In this case, after you install prophet just install TBATS using `pip install tbats`

Answer (score 0):

The general recommendation is to use the same package manager (`pip` or `conda`) for all the packages. But in cases where the package is unavailable on conda, you can use pip to install the specific package alone.

Further, it is advisable to do all this within virtual envs so that even if any inconsistencies arise, it stays within the virtual env. More info on creating envs using conda can be found [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).